# How can I implement the NAR bibliography style with biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, texstudio

I need to use the NAR bibliogrpahy style for a scientific paper. Unfortunately I can't manage to implement this style. I can't find the package which I guess I would need to install (?) so I constantly get the error message Package biblatex Error: Style 'nar' not found. \RequireBibliographyStyle{\blx@bbxfile}

This is in the preamble:

```
\usepackage[style=nar,backend=biber,sorting=none,defernumbers=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{literatur_Protokoll_Molmed.bib}
```

and this later where the bibliography is supposed to be:

```
\printbibliography
```

would be amazing if somebody could help!
best regards

Comment: I'm not familiar with the 'NAR' style: can you provide a link? What makes you think there is an existing `biblatex` style for this?

Comment: NAR is the nucleic acid research style. I was thinking that it must exist because of these links: https://www.bibtex.com/s/bibliography-style-misc-nar/ and https://ctan.org/pkg/nar

Comment: Those links are for a 'classical' BibTeX style, not one for `biblatex`.

Comment: Could you maybe explain how I could implement it with BibTex then? Unfortunately it's mandatory to use this style, but I am very new to LaTex so it's a little confusing.

Comment: @laura_s try https://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/thesis/html/bibtex.html#sec:bibtex. Short answer is use `\bibliography{bibfile}` where you want the bibliography and include `\bibliographystyle{nar}` in your document instead of the biblatex commands you give here. Then you need to run `bibtex` instead of `biber`.